# Xamarin IOS app crashes with exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, sigabrt

As soon as I open my app in iPhone 8 , it suddenly crashes from today. It was working fine till yesterday night.

This app is downloaded from app store which was published 3 weeks ago.
Previously I used to have Corrupt database error and it kept crashing, but today the log says some SIGABRT exception.

Here is the log file from Analytics data from the device:

```
{"app_name":"TCRMobile.iOS","timestamp":"2018-09-13 10:29:23.02 -0700","app_version":"1.0.0","slice_uuid":"e52d1787-ffb2-3fb1-b09d-84b215d718d1","adam_id":1401457455,"build_version":"10.0","bundleID":"com.tcrsoftware.xamuinotifapple","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)","incident_id":"003A2AF2-BC65-4652-A169-F8C846EE0704","name":"TCRMobile.iOS"}
Incident Identifier: 003A2AF2-BC65-4652-A169-F8C846EE0704
CrashReporter Key:   d4d6abeb1e3df984265e1c0c7a988192f95ecb8c
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,2
Process:             TCRMobile.iOS [24885]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5AFC7548-2281-49BD-B871-22E98BBE83D3/TCRMobile.iOS.app/TCRMobile.iOS
Identifier:          com.tcrsoftware.xamuinotifapple
Version:             10.0 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.tcrsoftware.xamuinotifapple [9417]


Date/Time:           2018-09-13 10:29:22.8880 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-09-13 10:29:22.1495 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)
Baseband Version:    4.60.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4378624000
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000104fc8000-0000000104fcc000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...TCRMobile.iOS

Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x183cf2d8c 0x182eac5ec 0x183cf2bf8 0x1846e2fa0 0x18d8cea80 0x18defeb1c 0x18d8cddd0 0x18d8cdc6c 0x18d8ccafc 0x18e56284c 0x18d8cc1ec 0x18e347ac8 0x18e495bf8 0x18d8cbc0c 0x18d8cb5a8 0x18d8c85e0 0x18d8c8330 0x1864f4470 0x1864fcd6c 0x1835e4a60 0x1835ec170 0x186528878 0x18652851c 0x186528ab8 0x183c9b404 0x183c9ac2c 0x183c9879c 0x183bb8da8 0x185b9e020 0x18dbd8758 0x105c60770 0x105bd927c 0x105bd923c 0x105034174 0x105311524 0x1068f445c 0x10696fb54 0x106972df8 0x1068d7944 0x106a295d8 0x105034000 0x183649fc0)

Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001837792e0 0x183757000 + 140000
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018391a288 0x183917000 + 12936
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001836e7d0c 0x183685000 + 404748
3   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000104fefbf8 0x104fc8000 + 162808
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183cf31c8 0x183bad000 + 1335752
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182eac8c8 0x182ea4000 + 35016
6   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000104fd16c4 0x104fc8000 + 38596
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182e9d37c 0x182e82000 + 111484
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182e9d400 0x182e82000 + 111616
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835e4a74 0x1835e3000 + 6772
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835ec170 0x1835e3000 + 37232
11  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000186528878 0x1864e8000 + 264312
12  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018652851c 0x1864e8000 + 263452
13  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000186528ab8 0x1864e8000 + 264888
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c9b404 0x183bad000 + 975876
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c9ac2c 0x183bad000 + 973868
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c9879c 0x183bad000 + 964508
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183bb8da8 0x183bad000 + 48552
18  GraphicsServices                0x0000000185b9e020 0x185b93000 + 45088
19  UIKit                           0x000000018dbd8758 0x18d8bb000 + 3266392
20  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105c60770 0x104fc8000 + 13207408
21  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105bd927c 0x104fc8000 + 12653180
22  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105bd923c 0x104fc8000 + 12653116
23  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105034174 0x104fc8000 + 442740
24  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105311524 0x104fc8000 + 3446052
25  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068f445c 0x104fc8000 + 26395740
26  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010696fb54 0x104fc8000 + 26901332
27  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000106972df8 0x104fc8000 + 26914296
28  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068d7944 0x104fc8000 + 26278212
29  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000106a295d8 0x104fc8000 + 27661784
30  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105034000 0x104fc8000 + 442368
31  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000183649fc0 0x183649000 + 4032

Thread 1 name:  tid_1203
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b04 0x183917000 + 2820

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183779d78 0x183757000 + 142712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917eb4 0x183917000 + 3764
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b08 0x183917000 + 2824

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001837790e8 0x183757000 + 139496
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018391bc90 0x183917000 + 19600
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000182e302ec 0x182e29000 + 29420
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b3416e8 0x18a86b000 + 11364072
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b341598 0x18a86b000 + 11363736
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b3410dc 0x18a86b000 + 11362524
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b340e18 0x18a86b000 + 11361816
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b341234 0x18a86b000 + 11362868
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919220 0x183917000 + 8736
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919110 0x183917000 + 8464
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b10 0x183917000 + 2832

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183757de8 0x183757000 + 3560
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183757c60 0x183757000 + 3168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c9ae40 0x183bad000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c98908 0x183bad000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183bb8da8 0x183bad000 + 48552
5   WebCore                         0x000000018be7c2d4 0x18be3b000 + 266964
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919220 0x183917000 + 8736
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919110 0x183917000 + 8464
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b10 0x183917000 + 2832

Thread 5 name:  SGen worker
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001837790e8 0x183757000 + 139496
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018391bc90 0x183917000 + 19600
2   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001069f10f8 0x104fc8000 + 27431160
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919220 0x183917000 + 8736
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919110 0x183917000 + 8464
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b10 0x183917000 + 2832

Thread 6 name:  Finalizer
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183757e24 0x183757000 + 3620
1   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010692d8e4 0x104fc8000 + 26630372
2   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010699d724 0x104fc8000 + 27088676
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919220 0x183917000 + 8736
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919110 0x183917000 + 8464
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b10 0x183917000 + 2832

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b04 0x183917000 + 2820

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183757de8 0x183757000 + 3560
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183757c60 0x183757000 + 3168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c9ae40 0x183bad000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c98908 0x183bad000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183bb8da8 0x183bad000 + 48552
5   Foundation                      0x000000018462d674 0x184625000 + 34420
6   Foundation                      0x000000018462d4dc 0x184625000 + 34012
7   UIKit                           0x000000018d8bd768 0x18d8bb000 + 10088
8   Foundation                      0x000000018473defc 0x184625000 + 1150716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919220 0x183917000 + 8736
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919110 0x183917000 + 8464
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b10 0x183917000 + 2832

Thread 9 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1c013cfc0.events
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183757e3c 0x183757000 + 3644
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835e702c 0x1835e3000 + 16428
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835e78a0 0x1835e3000 + 18592
3   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a47b888 0x18a478000 + 14472
4   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a48143c 0x18a478000 + 37948
5   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a48111c 0x18a478000 + 37148
6   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a4d7928 0x18a478000 + 391464
7   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a4d3988 0x18a478000 + 375176
8   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a4d3850 0x18a478000 + 374864
9   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a4d52ac 0x18a478000 + 381612
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000183952f30 0x18394e000 + 20272
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001839508c4 0x18394e000 + 10436
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835e4b30 0x1835e3000 + 6960
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835fb440 0x1835e3000 + 99392
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835ee86c 0x1835e3000 + 47212
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835fbeec 0x1835e3000 + 102124
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835ee86c 0x1835e3000 + 47212
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835ef2fc 0x1835e3000 + 49916
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835ee86c 0x1835e3000 + 47212
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835ef2fc 0x1835e3000 + 49916
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835efcc8 0x1835e3000 + 52424
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001835f8098 0x1835e3000 + 86168
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917e70 0x183917000 + 3696
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b08 0x183917000 + 2824

Thread 10 name:  tid_9303
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001837790e8 0x183757000 + 139496
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018391bc90 0x183917000 + 19600
2   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000106a06868 0x104fc8000 + 27519080
3   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001069930ac 0x104fc8000 + 27046060
4   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010699d724 0x104fc8000 + 27088676
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919220 0x183917000 + 8736
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919110 0x183917000 + 8464
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b10 0x183917000 + 2832

Thread 11 name:  Threadpool worker
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001837790e8 0x183757000 + 139496
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018391bc90 0x183917000 + 19600
2   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001069936a8 0x104fc8000 + 27047592
3   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010699d724 0x104fc8000 + 27088676
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919220 0x183917000 + 8736
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919110 0x183917000 + 8464
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b10 0x183917000 + 2832

Thread 12 name:  Threadpool worker
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018391c980 0x183917000 + 22912
1   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068b9340 0x104fc8000 + 26153792
2   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068b9340 0x104fc8000 + 26153792
3   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068b1588 0x104fc8000 + 26121608
4   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068b1f9c 0x104fc8000 + 26124188
5   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068f02e4 0x104fc8000 + 26378980
6   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068f6e20 0x104fc8000 + 26406432
7   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068f69bc 0x104fc8000 + 26405308
8   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010534233c 0x104fc8000 + 3646268
9   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010625b028 0x104fc8000 + 19476520
10  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105311524 0x104fc8000 + 3446052
11  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068f445c 0x104fc8000 + 26395740
12  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010696fb54 0x104fc8000 + 26901332
13  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010696cbf4 0x104fc8000 + 26889204
14  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068f0334 0x104fc8000 + 26379060
15  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068f6e20 0x104fc8000 + 26406432
16  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068f69bc 0x104fc8000 + 26405308
17  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010534233c 0x104fc8000 + 3646268
18  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000106226fc4 0x104fc8000 + 19263428
19  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000106226b10 0x104fc8000 + 19262224
20  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001061f1fb0 0x104fc8000 + 19046320
21  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001061f1e3c 0x104fc8000 + 19045948
22  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001061f1c3c 0x104fc8000 + 19045436
23  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105f903b0 0x104fc8000 + 16548784
24  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105ff470c 0x104fc8000 + 16959244
25  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105f80430 0x104fc8000 + 16483376
26  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105f90b4c 0x104fc8000 + 16550732
27  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105ff47e0 0x104fc8000 + 16959456
28  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105f805f8 0x104fc8000 + 16483832
29  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105f91464 0x104fc8000 + 16553060
30  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105ff4990 0x104fc8000 + 16959888
31  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105f814f8 0x104fc8000 + 16487672
32  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001051cb2d8 0x104fc8000 + 2110168
33  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001051d0254 0x104fc8000 + 2130516
34  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001051d0ad8 0x104fc8000 + 2132696
35  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001051bf194 0x104fc8000 + 2060692
36  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001051befec 0x104fc8000 + 2060268
37  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001051d0a00 0x104fc8000 + 2132480
38  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001051d0810 0x104fc8000 + 2131984
39  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001051d0658 0x104fc8000 + 2131544
40  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001051c402c 0x104fc8000 + 2080812
41  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105b90490 0x104fc8000 + 12354704
42  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001051c5e48 0x104fc8000 + 2088520
43  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000105311524 0x104fc8000 + 3446052
44  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001068f445c 0x104fc8000 + 26395740
45  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010696fb54 0x104fc8000 + 26901332
46  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000106995cdc 0x104fc8000 + 27057372
47  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001069934cc 0x104fc8000 + 27047116
48  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010699d724 0x104fc8000 + 27088676
49  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919220 0x183917000 + 8736
50  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183919110 0x183917000 + 8464
51  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183917b10 0x183917000 + 2832

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0xffffffffffffffff
    x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000018391a110  x11: 0x00000001b8431df4
   x12: 0x00000001b8431df4  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b6084b40  x21: 0x00000001ae657118  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b6084c20
   x24: 0x000000013be5b2d0  x25: 0x00000001b6092000  x26: 0x00000001b482a000  x27: 0x00000001c40fdc80
   x28: 0x0000000183d8939f   fp: 0x000000016ae35380   lr: 0x000000018391a288
    sp: 0x000000016ae35350   pc: 0x00000001837792e0 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x104fc8000 - 0x106c87fff TCRMobile.iOS arm64  <e52d1787ffb23fb1b09d84b215d718d1> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/5AFC7548-2281-49BD-B871-22E98BBE83D3/TCRMobile.iOS.app/TCRMobile.iOS
0x107448000 - 0x107483fff dyld arm64  <b15e536a710732dabfafece44c5685e4> /usr/lib/dyld
0x182e27000 - 0x182e28fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <0f3f5f4ea60d3d4d84af311421f67108> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x182e29000 - 0x182e81fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <e6172d25b5d63239879410136730d916> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x182e82000 - 0x182ea3fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <40c62b02df253630845890510fe3f773> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x182ea4000 - 0x18355ffff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <eb1135b2bde93b69b96e42ca98200183> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x183560000 - 0x183565fff libcache.dylib arm64  <a922e78994f33bb6a85162f25a9c7965> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x183566000 - 0x183571fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <d3ccb275f62c361bba490fa6a9bb383c> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x183572000 - 0x183575fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <82d8312d934c3f34b74d8df84e2cb55c> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x183576000 - 0x18357efff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <e07dded07d6f375d8fabfa20b0d5f6b5> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x18357f000 - 0x1835e2fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <68071da426b335bb860aed1483e03d6e> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1835e3000 - 0x183648fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <0c931ac760133de187bb6f440beed5eb> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x183649000 - 0x183663fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <6225b1cd39843071a64add8f31b09c36> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x183664000 - 0x183664fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <a25d2deb6e2d3c09a1085a5a79b16fdc> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x183665000 - 0x18366afff libmacho.dylib arm64  <797e8ee3e3b83978aaae2394e71ea6c3> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x18366b000 - 0x18366cfff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <a454faf6fd5e3f2fa3116507d634a357> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x18366d000 - 0x183683fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <833790f7db363b8e83b48eaec404a8aa> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x183684000 - 0x183684fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <a7c74cd6406f37d7a6beeb8faa6e1706> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x183685000 - 0x183702fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <61d2e950add73139aea459b55997ea48> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x183703000 - 0x183707fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <fc25fa74aabf399e9fa32acb529a8618> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x183708000 - 0x18370dfff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <db5dee3b17323c8aa68659a9c8dc9e76> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x18370e000 - 0x18370ffff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <64e24927a95a3b38a92af824aa262df3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x183710000 - 0x183711fff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64  <98cca712d0a63a819653681c52131ea2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x183712000 - 0x183718fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <1b83bbfe437639dd8bdb7353013ac147> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x183719000 - 0x183756fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <ebd778a7210c37408ee490f4564d4f5b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x183757000 - 0x18377ffff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <e102701ef8803cd4a5d54f5f14433dbd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x183780000 - 0x1837adfff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <3f43e403c5983d39ab50fa375c5c1bc9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x1837ae000 - 0x1837c9fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <6dd6981adef530b3b6062f29ade13bb2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1837ca000 - 0x1838f5fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <9ec043d8cb2538dc9ba84e324cd5b416> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x1838f6000 - 0x183901fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <7ed92c1b09023da8adac8c5073ca7566> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x183902000 - 0x18390cfff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <6400d5b3305b3f5d9d831e03e357943b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x18390d000 - 0x183916fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <97dae109bad63e588e5d63b8dbddadcf> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x183917000 - 0x183926fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <07c87e3874b73d128f0fa331d8894b97> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x183927000 - 0x18392afff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <5e76af73b50438c6b6a4827b7fb0b816> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x18392b000 - 0x183932fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <1a4f281f874131f68e00580a8110d629> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x183933000 - 0x183946fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <38618bae31eb39cfbfd4aa0e8df9e51b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x183947000 - 0x18394cfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <6288d2abbde239f293405082835ba85c> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x18394d000 - 0x18394dfff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <7afa9fbccf713115ad62383f8b379a85> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x18394e000 - 0x183978fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <05e40d4621113a32a4cdb7afc770b119> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x183979000 - 0x183b9afff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <a2f179b63753316d943b53a643e28199> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x183b9b000 - 0x183bacfff libz.1.dylib arm64  <cc396ca7a9d133d4898e573cc46ec982> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x183bad000 - 0x183f43fff CoreFoundation arm64  <533c841ed6e9313d8adb02388744e2ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x183f44000 - 0x183f54fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <b0ed5ab849a4342c835353a5d5533e06> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x183f55000 - 0x183f55fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <5195d5f14e163fc9bfc99099ae7a624f> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x183f56000 - 0x183fdafff IOKit arm64  <54433b44779d39378d0789a4017a2948> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x183fdb000 - 0x1840c2fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <187298f716873875b7a96317f9e2135a> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x1840c3000 - 0x1840d0fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <cdf0f19925fe33fbb5909928bc44fd5b> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x1840d1000 - 0x1840e9fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <deb8a124684f30729d528075ef8d61ef> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x1840ea000 - 0x18424efff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <219334ef89cf30099c3f85f925d853b3> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x18424f000 - 0x184275fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <ce9ab13d60fc3a678dfcab0f5347cc58> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x184276000 - 0x184624fff CFNetwork arm64  <ce119938b410382bb4481e599405ef23> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x184625000 - 0x18491dfff Foundation arm64  <2eacef3cb1e5323eac1a2e0d743c81a5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x18491e000 - 0x184a1ffff Security arm64  <b4a51fc3cb163f7b8786d8d37b56e515> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x184a20000 - 0x184a8bfff SystemConfiguration arm64  <658c4230686b3358a53006396fbe7605> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x184a8c000 - 0x184ac1fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <f44a46da006038f09432eb00a2b65697> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x184ac2000 - 0x184ac2fff libapple_crypto.dylib arm64  <0a68153dfbfc33b096374e95fb1271bd> /usr/lib/libapple_crypto.dylib
0x184ac3000 - 0x184ad9fff libapple_nghttp2.dylib arm64  <8bb1455b0f653519956db1c8af6d57a1> /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib
0x184ada000 - 0x184b03fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <4590f76c617938f7a3a9e248ecc42d44> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x184b04000 - 0x184bb2fff libboringssl.dylib arm64  <477924cf769f35239a5c6b9b2c6473bd> /usr/lib/libboringssl.dylib
0x184bb3000 - 0x184bc9fff libcoretls.dylib arm64  <193a4fc806793432a8b2bb3d8a6a8ec4> /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
0x184bca000 - 0x184bcbfff libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib arm64  <09de65296b06366694578620bf512d8d> /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
0x184bcc000 - 0x184bcdfff liblangid.dylib arm64  <ca04122dcd66354db9a53d9f0e91f855> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x184bce000 - 0x184d44fff libnetwork.dylib arm64  <b5da178f015038d4ad82288ff8cbca37> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x184d45000 - 0x184d77fff libpcap.A.dylib arm64  <5389a8069179359eb6822edd62328659> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
0x184d78000 - 0x184dd4fff libusrtcp.dylib arm64  <ba4a0d2e24dd3ea0a9307b03598564cc> /usr/lib/libusrtcp.dylib
0x184dd5000 - 0x184ddffff IOSurface arm64  <1f24b80565013f8d94b5e18c144f24bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x184de0000 - 0x184e85fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <bda6fa96025e3513848156f93c78ddc0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x184e86000 - 0x1851a6fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <e32d2bce3c353d4f80205fc0731e4e07> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x1851a7000 - 0x185416fff vImage arm64  <b864841843df38bb99e1dff0e1d24732> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x185417000 - 0x185428fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <32a953927bdf3e46b9d154bf8980fb63> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x185429000 - 0x18544dfff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <7ada6cde719335328636b01d59e23ea9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x18544e000 - 0x185475fff libBNNS.dylib arm64  <fa4ef0a7739237d4a3316c137346c5ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBNNS.dylib
0x185476000 - 0x18548afff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <b41f21090a7c3472aeb495fd2712eea4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework
```

EOF

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you debuged it on simulator?

Comment: it's happened on a testing device. The device is not with me. And this is random crash. so unable to debug

Comment: Going forward, please post the symbolicated crash log; we can't read or understand the machine addresses in the log.